# How to add transition on UITapGestureRecognizer in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to make the image view full screen when I click on the small image. But the image show very fast when I clicked on the image. Can I add some transition time to delay the full screen image showing?

```
@IBAction func uploadImgAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let tapgesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(DeleteJobViewController.tap))
    tapgesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    reasonImg.addGestureRecognizer(tapgesture)
}

func tap(){
    print("tap")
    let newImageView = UIImageView(image: reasonImg.image)
    newImageView.frame = self.view.frame
    newImageView.backgroundColor = .black
    newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    newImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissFullscreenImage))
    newImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    self.view.addSubview(newImageView)
}

func dismissFullscreenImage(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    sender.view?.alpha = 1
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, animations: {
        sender.view?.alpha = 0
        sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
    })
}
```

Comment: Use [`transition(with:duration:options:animation:completion:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622574-transition). That's one easy way animate the change of a view hierarchy. The other approach is to animate the change of some property (e.g. the `alpha`) and then do any post processing in the completion block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the `self.view.addSubview(newImageView)` line with:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {   
  UIView.transition(with: self.view, duration:0.6, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.showHideTransitionViews, animations: {
    self.view.addSubview(self.newImageView)
  }, completion: nil)
}
```

You can also try setting `newImageView.alpha = 0` before running this code:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, animations: {
  self.newImageView.alpha = 1.0
})
```

For animating the disappear effect, in the code above, replace the `addSubview` statement with `newImageView.removeFromSuperview()`.
And similarly you can set this after you have set the `newImageView.alpha = 1`:

```
func dismissFullscreenImage(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, animations: {
          self.newImageView.alpha = 0
    })
}
```

EDIT:

Please add `newImageView` as a property at the top of your view controller.

Then in your `tap` function set this instead of `let newImageView`:

```
self.newImageView = UIImageView(image: reasonImg.image)
```

Now if you run the code it should compile.

Comment: how about add transition on removeSuperView? I tried to add UIView.transition to it, but not working.

Comment: I updated my dismiss code at answer, why Its not working?

Comment: which approach the `alpha` property or the `removeFromSubview`?

Comment: the alpha property

Comment: you need to use `UIView.animate` for animating the `alpha` property. I have added the code for this above.

Comment: I got unrelsoved identifier on 'newImageView'

Answer (score 0):

```
    yourImageView.alpha = 0

    *your addSubview in the middle

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
    yourImageView.alpha = 1
    })
```

First set your image to be invisible, then animate (in my example for 0.5 sec) to be visible.

Comment: how about adding transition on removeSuperView?

Comment: @WanJern well, same thing, just opposite, alpha from 1 to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
func tap() {
   print("tap")
   let newImageView = UIImageView(image: reasonImg.image)
   newImageView.frame = self.view.frame
   newImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 0.0, y: 0.0)
   newImageView.backgroundColor = .black
   newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
   newImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
   let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissFullscreenImage))
   newImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
   self.view.addSubview(newImageView)

   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            newImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
   })
}
```